# ViewModelLocator.LocateForView returns new Model, not the model ContentControl is bound

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a ContentControl in xaml defined as:

```
 <ContentControl Micro:View.Model="{Binding ProductionGrid}" />
```

I use the View.Model as the control is embedded in a docking panel.

My ViewModel has the property defined and it set in the constructor of the ViewModel and uses constructor injection to create the instance.

The View gets instantiated, but I cannot access the model that was created in the ViewModel, it seems to create a new model when trying to get the instance from the xaml.cs constructor of the View.

```
var model = Caliburn.Micro.ViewModelLocator.LocateForView(this) as DynamicDataGridViewModel;
```

How can I correctly get the model that should be associated with the View when it's created?

Answer (score 0):

If the ContentControl is embedded in a docking panel you can just name the ContentControl `x:Name="ProductionGrid`" and shouldn't need `Micro:View.Model="{Binding ProductionGrid}"`

> The View gets instantiated, but I cannot access the model that was
>   created in the ViewModel, it seems to create a new model when trying
>   to get the instance from the xaml.cs constructor of the View.

You mean the ViewModel gets instantiated?

So the binding works?  I'd have to look but I don't know if CM will find ProductionGridView from ProductionGrid, it might, I'm not sure.  ProductionGridViewModel and ProductionGridView would work.

You shouldn't need to code anything in the xaml.cs constructor, in fact, I delete the xaml.cs files.

Comment: I did try just using the ContentControl name parameter, however, it did not work for whatever reason. The docking panel is third party.

The problem was/is that the View gets created but is not "attached" to the ViewModel early enough for me to access it from the View constructor (nor could it really). 

Normally I wouldn't try to code in the xaml.cs, however i was trying to re-use a control and not re-write it. 

In the end i made my ViewModel derive from ViewAware and used the OnViewAttached to do what I needed. I did have to re-write a lot of the control anyway.